# An explanation for going from $|x\log x| < 1, \forall x \in (0,1)$ to $|x^a \log x| < 1/a$ (Real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How do I go from $|x\log x < 1|, \forall x \in (0,1)$ to $|x^a \log x| < 1/a,a > 0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the first inequality using $x^a$ in place of $x$.

This is valid for positive $a$ because $0<x<1$ if and only if $0<x^a<1$.

This gives you $$|x^a\log x^a|<1$$
$$|x^a(a\log x)|<1$$
$$a|x^a\log x|<1$$
$$|x^a\log x|<\frac1a$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$a|x^a \log x|= |x^a \log x^a|$$

Set $y=x^a$ and use $|y \log y|<1$.

Comment: Now I get it. Since $x \in (0,1) \implies x^a \in (0,1)$. Thanks. Btw, I do not know why I got downvoted for this question.

Comment: You got a "close" vote because you didn't show any work.

Comment: This is in the middel of my work, which consists of to pages for a problem. I think that's a bit too harsh :)